# How to save variables on access storage without a table?

Tags: database, ms-access

I've protected delete queries on my forms with a password (did it with some VBA) and I let the user change the password so I can't just compare it to a text when I ask the user to enter the password, is there any way I could save the password variable on access storage without a table?

currently, I'm saving the password on a table with one field and doing the comparisons at the background...

It's a school project.

Comment: You can store it in database properties. See [`CreateProperty`](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-09.html)

Comment: @SergeyS. I'd like it to be changeable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the password, but better password hash as advised **@Lee Mac** in the database properties. Property can be changed at any time by code. Change remains in the database file after database closing.
Create property:

```
Function CreatePropery()
    Dim DB As Database
    Dim P As Property
    Set DB = CurrentDb
    Set P = DB.CreateProperty("MyPassword", DB_TEXT, "MyInitialPassword")
    DB.Properties.Append P
End Function
```

Get current password:

```
Function GetPasswod()
    GetPasswod = CurrentDb.Properties![MyPassword]
End Function
```

Set new password:

```
Function SetPassword(strNewPassword As String)
    CurrentDb.Properties![MyPassword] = strNewPassword
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest hashing the password and storing the hash in your table; then, when the user enters a password, hash the entered password and compare the result with the stored hash.

This approach has the benefit that no passwords are stored in human readable format, and the hashing process cannot be reversed to yield the plain text password from the stored hash (one could only brute-force guess the password and compare the resulting hash).